# GAMLSS - Error in seq.default(xl - deg * dx, xr + deg * dx, by = dx) : 'from' must be a finite number

Tags: r, gamlss

I am using the R package GAMLSS to fit a GAM to illustrate the seasonality (by `month`) and trend (`week_t` number in a year) in a time series data (`mydat`)
Here is the code I ran:

```
fit_lss <- gamlss(num_travelers ~ pb(month) + pb(week_t),
                  data = na.omit(mydat),  family = "PO")
```

However, I got an error message:

```
Error in seq.default(xl - deg * dx, xr + deg * dx, by = dx) : 
  'from' must be a finite number
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

I am very much appreciated it if anyone helps me fix the error.
Thank you.

I have no clue of how to solve it at the moment.

Comment: Your code works with a synthetic dataset, so you'll need to share your data, or similar data that creates the same error. A good way to do that is `dput(head(mydat,20))`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I have found the problem and finally the code is running without errors.
The problem is there are other variables in `mydat` that are not included in the GAM formula, so that it causes the error.
After eliminating uneccessary variables, the code works now. Thanks again.